# Is it possible to associate a hyperlink to string in mule 4 response?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I am trying to build a flow, where I want to show an URL(hyperlink) in the response, which on click will open another flow end-point.

Example:
GET /list

output:

```
{
  "object" :{
"accounts" : **url**,
"customer" : **url**
}
}
```

I want to add the hyperlink in the url (show in bold in output), which on clicking will open another flow passing either "accounts" or "customer" to the other flow as end-point.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The example indicates that the response is a JSON and I guess you are receiving it from a browser. You can add the hyperlink as the value of the attributes. However JSON doesn't have an URL data type, so the URLs will need to be strings, surrounded by quotes. Note that it is up to the browser to decide if those URLs are 'clickable' or just plain text.

Comment: How to make text as hyperlink (clickable) in Mule 4?

Comment: What do you mean by clickable exactly? Mule doesn't has a user interface, there is nothing to click. Only a client application may display the output in a graphical way that include links. What you are asking doesn't make sense without further context on what is exactly the client and how it will recognize URLs.

Comment: I do agree Mule does not have user interface. But Mule have the capability to send email. And we have a requirement where we need to send one URL endpoint in the email. Now this URL is something which needs to be seen entirely. Just "Link" text with hyperlink of endpoint. So how we can leverage this ?

Comment: That's different than this question. You should post a new question with your specific use case.